# When will the Fruits Basket reboot start airing?

Tags: crunchyroll, fruits-basket

It will show this year, but when is the exact date it will air?  Funimation and the team in Japan have officially announced to a simulcast meaning the agreement make it together aired and was an effort to decide to decide what time  was aleady reviewed and decided.  My research was able to find that it appeared to be in an agreement for early April to begin.

Answer (score 2):

No exact date has been given yet other than "April 2019."

Source: https://comicbook.com/anime/2019/01/19/fruits-basket-reboot-character-designs-additional-cast/

Comment: See [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for some guidance, @fingertrick ;)

Comment: @JNat thank you due to the scrutiny I am countering information to warrant my comments and questions and rules.  I wrote a detailed examination of the reason why whoever put this on hold off topic wasn't fitting with the specific information.  Further more my edit to Allieon needs approval or it may not make not show why it didn't meet put on hold-of topic.  This is likely helpful as a comment to clarify a situation.